# Is there a way to generate left and right camera views from one camera video

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion, 3d

I have only one video available from one camera. Is it possible to create left and right camera views from one camera video and could be viewed from oculus rift-VR. No need for audio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have used  IQMango 3D Converter and the result is impressive

http://iqmango.com/3DVideo_Converter.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. However, you can't do it with ffmpeg.

Automatically creating a 3D picture from a 2D source is a hard problem, since there is no actual depth information or any disparate source image to work with. This kind of [automatic 2D-to-3D conversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2D_to_3D_conversion#Automatic_conversion) will therefore look quite bad if not done properly—and even then, you might have troubles  watching the material for longer periods of time, as unnatural depth cues can cause nausea or headaches.

The Wikipedia article lists a few programs that perform this conversion, and doing a web search should also give you quite a few (commercial) programs to try.

Comment: Thank you  - wiki lists Gimpel3D also. Do you have any experience with this or any other software. Is there any method to convert to virtual reality and view using Oculus Rift (depth accuracy is not very critical).

Comment: I haven't tried any 2D-to-3D software yet, so I cannot give you any specific pointers, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

[Poppy3D](http://poppy3d.com/) uses mirrors to split the sensor so that you can have two cameras with one lens/sensor